# Why this jQuery code works only for one Iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, live

Basically I have a drop icon, which should expand and collpase an area beneath it. It changes the background position and points downwards and shows some content.On click again it collapses the content and changes the background position. below is what i have written but it doesn't work properly.

```
$(function() {
    $(".aclass").live('click' , function() {
        $(this).css("background-position","-156px -42px").addClass("new");

        $(".blockedDiv").hide();
        $(".mystery").css("max-height","189px");
    });

    $(".new").live('click', function() {
        $(this).css("background-position","0px 0px");
        $(".blockedDiv").show();
        $(".mystery").css("max-height","1007px");
    });
});
```

My two questions:
1: Why is this working only for one Iteration
2: Is there a better way to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean iteration? I don't see any loops here.

Comment: It mean it works only for the first click

Comment: which part of this works? and which does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not removing the `new` class you added. Because of that, when you click on it again, the second event handler fires as well, reversing what the first event handler did.

As a side note-slash-tip, what you want is to specify explicit CSS rules, which you can toggle with jQuery, so that you don't have to muck through (relatively) complicated logic.

```
.mystery { max-height:10007px; }
.mystery.flagged { max-height:189px; }

.aclass { background-position:0 0; }
.aclass.flagged { background-position:-156px -42px; }
```

then in your jQuery:

```
$('.aclass').live('click', function () {
    $('.mystery').toggleClass('flagged');
    $(this).toggleClass('flagged');
    $('.blockedDiv').toggle();
});
```

Comment: .live() has been deprecated in favor of .on()

Comment: Thanks Richard, Is there any compact way of doing this.

Comment: @bpeterson76: which version has on defined in it.I used on and it threw error

Comment: @bpeterson76 ~ I know, but without the supporting HTML markup, I can't fashion an effective `bind` or `delegate`, much less an `on`. Just working with what I have here. :)

Comment: @Mike ~ `.on` is with jQuery 1.7.x. And about compacting your code, throw in some HTML and we can perhaps work on getting it optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Richard has already pointed out the problem with your code already. You need to toggle the `new` class.

A cleaner way to this is probably using the `toggleClass()` jQuery function.

You define two CSS classes:

```
.hiddenDiv {...}
.expandedIcon {...}
.collapsedIcon {...}
```

And JS:

```
$(function(){
   $(".aClass").click(function(){
         $(".blockDiv").toggleClass("hiddenDiv");
         $(this).toggleClass("expandedIcon");
         $(this).toggleClass("collapsedIcon");

    });
})
```

And in your HTML, have something like:

```
<div class="aClass collapsedIcon"> </div> <!-- initially collapsed -->
<div class="blockDiv hiddenDiv"> </div> <!-- initially hidden -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different way of doing it that should work.

```
$(function() {
    $(".aclass").live('click' , function() {
        var $this = $(this), // cache the result of the function to prevent recreating it each time
            is_expanded = $this.hasClass('new');
        $this.css({'background-position': (is_expanded ? '-156px -42px' : '0px 0px')});
        $('.mystery').css({'max-height': (is_expanded ? '189px' : '1007px')});
        if (is_expanded) {
            $('.blockedDiv').show();
            $this.removeClass('new');
        } else {
            $('.blockedDiv').hide();
        }
        $this.addClass('new'); // won't do anything if it already has the class
    });
});
```

EDIT: As @Richard Neil Ilagan mentioned, you (and I) forgot to remove the `new` class.

Answer (score 0):

It's working just fine. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHBWS/3/)

**Click ".aclass" and it will:**
1) set the background-position of 'this'
2) add the class "new" (which makes it a target for BOTH handlers now)
3) hide a different thing .blockedDiv
4) set the max-height of .mystery

**Click ".new" and it will:**
1) set the background-position of 'this'
2) show a different thing .blockedDiv
3) set the max-height of .mystery

What did you intend for it to do? Maybe you wanted to remove the class .aclass int he first handler, and do the opposite in the second (add .aclass remove .new)?